# current divider problem

Tags: resistors, current-divider

[image]

$$R_1=27kOhms ,R_2=56kOhms,R_3=50kOhms,V_s=5V$$
I'm trying to find the current thats flowing through R3, what i did was to convert the voltage source and resistors R1+R2 into a current source and then i use current divider formula to solve R3: I3=Is((R1+R2)/(R1+R2)+R3. Is that correct?

Comment: The current through R3 is just Vs/R3. No need to make it complicated in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct.
In this case, left circuit and right circuit work independent: the current flowing through the left part (R3) does not depend on the current that flows through the right side (R1, R2).  As Andres just pointed out, I3=Vs/R3

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fel8lZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Running the simulation above matches the analytical result:

$$i_1 = \frac {5 \ \text{V}} {27 \ \text{k}\Omega + 56 \ \text{k}\Omega} = 60.2 \ \mu\text{A}$$

$$i_3 = \frac {5 \ \text{V}} {50 \ \text{k}\Omega} = 100 \ \mu\text{A}$$

$$V_{\text{out}} = i_1 R_2 = 3.37 \ \text{V}$$